# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: soap

I am receiving the following error when trying to connect to SOAP api - the location of the test file is http://www.fontrubidesign.com/juniper/hello.php and the error I am getting is below:

```
    XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://www.fontrubidesign.com/juniper/hello.php
Line Number 1, Column 7:

object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
------^
```

The code I am using to test the connection is:

```
try {
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.fontrubidesign.com/juniper/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120,'compression'=> SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,'trace'=>true,'exceptions'=>true));

$session = $client->login(array(
        'username' => 'user',
        'apiKey' => 'password')
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $client->__getLastResponse();
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I read that the problem can occur if the server is unable to read the contents of the URL. This would mean that the host entry is missing in the servers hosts file. But I am not sure if this solves the problem.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what the soap foalt is actually about? object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ... } ? Disable WSDL Cache for debugging.